# Reduce the width of the covering layout in SlidePaneLayout Android in closed state

Tags: android, slide, navigation-drawer, android-layout-weight

When SlidePaneLayout is closed it covers the entire window,
I need to see the background when the slidePaneLayout is in closed state.

i.e., Covering layout should cover 80% and the background should be visible for the rest 20%.

Like you see in the Navigation Drawer,

I have tried all the tutorials and libraries, Is there any simple solutions like setting the layout_weight or layout_width?.

I tried it but it didn't work.

Could someone please help.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:windowBackground="@android:color/black"
     android:id="@+id/sp" > 

     <!-- Left side pane. (Master) --> 
     <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/leftpane" 
         android:layout_width="250dp" 
         android:layout_height="match_parent" 
         android:background="#DFDEFF"
         android:orientation="horizontal" >
         </LinearLayout> 

         <!-- Right side page. (Slave) --> 
         <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/rightpane" 
             android:layout_width="0px" 
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_weight="1"          
             android:background="#FFFFFF"
             android:orientation="horizontal">
         </LinearLayout> 

</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the background one's `layout_width` to a suitable number.
The covering one's `layout_width` **should not** be '0dp'! Just be any number,so much as "match_parent".

The content panel always be set to "match_parent whatever you set.

the left panel and the right panel(the content panel) are not in the same plane.

Comment: I tried this, but now the sliding is not working. I have attached the slidePaneLayout code with the question. could you please help

Comment: I got the answer. its **layout_marginLeft** that needs to be set. Posted it below. thanks for trying.